# Why does usernametwo always get skipped?

Tags: c++, io, cin, getline

I am trying to learn C++, anyway I am on if statements.

I coded a program that ask a two user their full name and ages (fictional users), it ask user1 its name and age and user2 the same, but somehow asking the user2's name gets skipped and end up asking the user2's age

why ?

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string usernameone;
    string usernametwo;
    int age1;
    int age2;

    //ask the users their name and age
    cout << "Hi may I know your full name ? : ";
    getline ( cin, usernameone, '\n');
    cout << "\nHello " << usernameone << " May I know now whats your age ? : ";
    cin >> age1;
    cout << "Ok thanks for the information, now may I talk to the other user ? thanks.\n\n";
    cout << "Hello may I know your full name ? : ";
    getline ( cin, usernametwo, '\n');
    cout << "\nHello " << usernametwo << " May I know now whats your age ? : ";
    cin >> age1;

    if(age1 < age2)
    {
        cout << "looks like " << usernameone << " is older than " << usernametwo;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ok " << usernametwo << " is older than " << usernameone;
    }

    if(age2 && age1 >= 100)
    {
        cout << "your both lying your age can't be 100 and above";
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not going to call them out if only one of them is lying?

Comment: You are mixing line-based input (`getline`) with item-based input (`cin >> x`). The `cin >> x` will leave a newline in the input buffer, so you either need to add code to clear that, or use `getline` for both and convert to integer from string. This is a very common problem...

Comment: Two issues: You wrote `cin >> age1;` two times. I guess the second is supposed to be `cin >> age2;`. Then `if(age2 && age1 >= 100)` is the same as `if (age2 != 0 && age1 >= 100)`. It should be `if (age2 >= 100 && age1 >= 100)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MatsPetersson there is cin.ignore() there

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: but too late to have any effect on the code that reads the user-name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cin >> age1;
cout << "Ok thanks for the information, now may 
         I talk to the other user ? thanks.\n\n";
cout << "Hello may I know your full name ? : ";
```

leaves `'\n'` in input stream and you are reading it in the next read

```
getline ( cin, usernametwo, '\n');
```

You can ignore this character with:

```
    cin >> age1;
    cout << "Ok thanks for the information, now may 
             I talk to the other user ? thanks.\n\n";
    cout << "Hello may I know your full name ? : ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline ( cin, usernametwo, '\n');
```